# Exception when having referenceMap with CsvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

i am tring to write to a csv file with help of csvHelper, but I got the exception

> Property 'System.String Type** is not defined for type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ParsingTest1.BookRecord]

The result I want to achieve is a csv file like this

```
05, Henrik, Data
06, Henrik Kodar, 2012
06, Henrik bakar, 2013
05, Fredrik, IT
06, Henrik Kodar, 2012
```

I have looked in to the [quick start reference](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and asked Mr Google but we can not find why. I copy a sample code that I working with.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var book1 = new BookRecord
    {
        Type = "06",
        Title = "Henrik kodar",
        Year = "2012"
    };

    var book2 = new BookRecord
    {
        Type = "06",
        Title = "Henrik bakar",
        Year = "2013"
    };


    var person = new PersonRecord
    {
        Type = "05",
        Name = "Henrik",
        Profession = "data"
    };

    person.BookRecords.Add(book1);
    person.BookRecords.Add(book2);

    var person1 = new PersonRecord
    {
        Type = "05",
        Name = "Test",
        Profession = "data"
    };

    person1.BookRecords.Add(book1);
    person1.BookRecords.Add(book2);

    var listan = new List<PersonRecord> { person };


    var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Development\bookz.csv");
    var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(sr);
    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();
    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<BookRecordMap>();
    csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(listan);


    sr.Flush();
    sr.Close();
    }
}

public class PersonRecord
{
    public PersonRecord()
    {
        BookRecords = new List<BookRecord>();
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
    public List<BookRecord> BookRecords { get; set; }
}

public class BookRecord
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : CsvClassMap<PersonRecord>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Type).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Profession).Index(2);
        References<BookRecordMap>(m => m.BookRecords);
    }
}

public class BookRecordMap : CsvClassMap<BookRecord>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(b => b.Type).Index(0);
        Map(b => b.Title).Index(0);
        Map(b => b.Year).Index(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write `IEnumerable`s using mapping files. The only way is to do it manually.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151066/68499